# How to make Radiobuttons detect when a button is already pushed?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make it so when a button is already pressed it says that it is already pressed. Any ideas how to do so?

```
from tkinter import *

selected = ()

def push():
    if (x.get()) == 0:
        if selected == "pizza":
            print("pizza is already selected")
        else:
            selected = ("pizza")
            print("you have selected pizza")
    elif(x.get()) == 1:
        print("you selected cheeseburger")
    else:
        print("you selected hotdog")

food = ["pizza", "Cheeseburger", "hotdog"]

window = Tk()
window.title("radio buttons")
window.geometry("500x500")

x = IntVar()

for index in range(len(food)):
    radiobutton = Radiobutton(window,
        text=food[index],
        variable=x,
        value=index,
        padx = 25,
        pady=25,
        font=("impact", 50),
        indicatoron=0,
        width= 100,
        command=push
    )
    radiobutton.pack(anchor=W)

window.mainloop()
```

In the push function I'm tried adding selected = "" and then later when the button is pushed say selected = ("pizza") but it always never changed from "" to pizza

Comment: Why not make the `value=` option of your radiobuttons be the foods themselves, rather than the indexes?  (And also make `x` a StringVar, of course.)  You can then just do `x.get()` for the final selection, no further code necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Here is it what I came up with (it changes only the function "push"):

```
selected = -1
def push():
    global selected
    if x.get() == 0:
        if selected == 0:
            print("pizza is already selected")
        else:
            print("you have selected pizza")
            selected = 0
    elif x.get() == 1:
        if selected == 1:
            print("hamburger is already selected")
        else:
            print("you have selected hamburger")
            selected = 1
    else:
        if selected == 2:
            print("hotdog is already selected")
        else:
            print("you have selected hotdog")
            selected = 2
```

Now the explanation comes. First, you create the global variable "selected" which keeps track of what has been chosen. Initially, it is assigned to be -1 because when it was assigned to be, let's say, 1, your program would print that "pizza is already selected" - which is not true at the very beginning. Second, you've got first if statement which radio button is chosen and the second if statement inside, which determines whether this button has been already chosen or not.
Feel free to ask any question!